# Kindly for closing email!

Tags: usage, correspondence

I would like to inquire about the usage of word "kindly" to close an email instead of "best", "sincerely" or ....etc.

Can the word "kindly" be used to close an email, for example:

> Hi Matt,
>   I would like to thank you for the great help yesterday!
>   kindly,
>   John

I see it very strange, but many people in my institution are using it to close their emails! Kindly, is this usage of "kindly" is correct?

Comment: If you _did_ decide to use it, it should be spelled with an upper-case _k_.

Comment: @JR. thanks for the comment. Would you please clarify. not clear?

Comment: Email messages are informal, and don't have to follow the structure of a letter (unless dictated by rules/conventions of your organization).  Communications people suggest keeping email short and efficient, leaving out superfluous niceties that are part of formal correspondence (like a closing word or phrase).  If the communication needs to be long or it is appropriate to include the frills, a letter might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it could work, but it sounds strange and I wouldn't recommend it.

If you want to use the word "kind", then consider these:

> Kind regards/wishes, John.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really  a question of English grammar but relates to what might be fashionable in one institution and not in another. There is an enormous vocabulary of words (more or less meaningless) that have from time to time be used to signify a respectful end to  a conversation (nowadays to an email). "Tonk! tonk!" takes my prize for the most meaningless, but in a strong field.

My guess is that someone wanted to make a variation on "Sincerely" and thought of using "Kindly". "Sincerely" is an abbreviation of such forms as "Yours Sincerely" which are themselves abbreviations of the very elaborate forms that were once used, such as "Believe me, my Lord, your Lordship's devoted and humble servant".